# Sending 'exec' commands to Docker container using Java

Tags: java, docker, terminal

I'm trying to send docker commands using Java Runtime.
Commands like `docker cp` works very nice with the below method as well as typing directly from the terminal.

1. First problem is that the `docker exec` command works only from the terminal, not with the Java Runtime. Other docker commands like `docker cp` works as expected. The only problem is that I can't run commands on the container, like echoing on the container's terminal.
2. Also the 2nd problem is that the `System.out.println(...)`method in the below method, doesn't actually print anything.

```
private static void runCommand() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                new String[]{"/bin/sh",
                        "-c",
                        "docker exec -u 0 -it <CONTAINER_NAME> echo",  "'abc'"});
        BufferedReader reader =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.print(line + "\n");
        }
        proc.waitFor();
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to execute docker commands through Java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37810115/how-to-execute-docker-commands-through-java-program)

Comment: Unfortunately not. I can already send docker commands, the problem is to send the commands that will be run inside the container with 'exec' command.

Comment: Would it not be better to use the API? https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java/wiki

Comment: @Anil hello, did you resolved this? I am also trying to do something similar.
I want to connect to wildfly container and do deployment disable.
please let me know if you got it resolved.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to run docker inside a shell. You can start the process directly. 
As of Java 1.7 you can also use [ProcessBuilder.inheritIO()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO--) to redirect the standard I/O of the subprocess

Below a working example that prints the output of the `echo` command:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
processBuilder.command("docker", "exec" , "-it", "<CONTAINER_NAME_OR_ID>", "echo", "abc").inheritIO();

try {
  Process process = processBuilder.start();
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

  String line;
  while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
  }

  int exitCode = process.waitFor();
  System.out.println("\nExited with error code : " + exitCode);

} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope this helps.