# How can I execute predefined docker command from Java application with DockerClient?

Tags: java, docker, docker-api

I have Java Maven project with com.github.docker-java dependency.
There is poor documentation and I have no idea, how to call this command:

```
docker run --rm -v "$(pwd)":/browsertime sitespeedio/browsertime:16.3.0 --video --visualMetrics https://www.sitespeed.io/
```

I know, that I can exec command directly, but I think that using Java API would be preferred.

So what Java code that uses DockerClient will run command above properly?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you checked this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37810115/how-to-execute-docker-commands-through-java-program