# How to run docker command from Java Application directly using Runtime?

Tags: java, docker

I hava Java project and I want to execute docker command from my code. Command:

```
docker run --rm -v "$(pwd)":/browsertime sitespeedio/browsertime:16.3.0 --video --visualMetrics https://www.sitespeed.io/
```

I have tried to write Java class with following code inside `main`-method:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("docker run --rm -v \"$(pwd)\":/browsertime sitespeedio/browsertime:16.3.0 --video --visualMetrics https://www.sitespeed.io/");
```

This has compiled fine and got the result in console "Process finished with exit code 0", so everything has been okey, but no result had been got (that command had to create folders and files and so on...).

So how should I run that docker command? If you have answer using `DockerClient` (not directly using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec`)  - then go here: [How can I execute predefined docker command from Java application with DockerClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72168223/how-can-i-execute-predefined-docker-command-from-java-application-with-dockercli)

Comment: Step back. First of all, learn how to use the ProcessBuilder interface (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856028/difference-between-processbuilder-and-runtime-exec) ... then understand: your initial command line is ran by a SHELL. Therefore things like env wars like `$(pwd)` work. There is no magic that fills up that `$(pwd)` when you send a command string within java. YOUR code has to make sure that the correct path information is already in that string that you "send down" to be executed!

Comment: Also make sure the java program doing this has the neccessary privileges to create/modify the files and folders. The command will inherit the same privileges that the java program has.

Comment: Using a [Docker SDK](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdk/), like [docker-java](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java), will probably be easier and safer than trying to run a `docker` shell command.  But do remember that the ability to launch a Docker container at all comes with the power to root the entire host, and that this approach won't necessarily be portable to other container runtimes.

Comment: Here is an example of how I did this in the past: https://github.com/jonckvanderkogel/elasticsearch-research/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/elasticsearchresearch/configuration/support/ElasticSearchSetupRunner.java

Comment: @GhostCat+ actually `$(pwd)` is command substitution; variable expansion is `${PWD}` or `$PWD` (and it can be _either_ a shell variable or an environmental variable). But the main point is correct that _both_ of these (and more) work only in shell not java.